# Travel across the Poincaré disk model of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

*A* is a point on the Poincaré disk model of the hyperbolic plane.  *B* is a second point, *d* hyperbolic distance away from *A*.  The hyperbolic ray *AB* passes through *A* at angle *θ*.

How might one find the coordinates of *B*, given *A*, *d*, and *θ*?

In other words, how would one answer a question like this:

> Beginning at Euclidean position (-.3, .4) on the Poincaré disk, one turns to face Northwest (3π / 2 radians) and travels 3 units.  Where does one end up?

Is enough information given?

Comment: $\theta$: the angle of $AB$ to what other line?

Comment: relative to the x axis

Comment: What is the angle of $AB$ to the $x$ axis if the two don't intersect within the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: then, relative to the line parallel to the x axis (parallel in the Euclidean sense), which passes through _A_

Comment: In other words, the slope of the tangent line of _AB_ at _A_ is equal to tan(_θ_).

Comment: Are your coordinates given in hyperbolic units or are they given in Euclidean units? $3\frac{\pi}{2}$ NW = E?

Comment: Coordinates are Euclidean.  I've updated the question to clarify.  An angle of 3π/2 radians is equivalent to "NW."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a hyperbolic triangle from $A$, $B$, and the center of the unit circle, $C$.  Let $a$ be the length of $BC$, $b$ the length of $AC$, and $c$ the length of $AB$.  Let $\alpha$, and $\gamma$ be the values of $\angle CAB$  and $\angle ACB$, respectively.

The value of $c$ is given as distance $d$:
$$c = d$$

The value of $\alpha$ is determined from the angle of $A$ relative to the unit circle, $\epsilon$; and the angle correspondent to the given direction of travel, $\delta$:
$$\alpha = |\pi - |\epsilon - \delta||$$

The value of $b$ can be determined based on the Euclidean distance from the center of the unit circle to $A$, $d_A$:
$$b = 2 \operatorname{arctanh}(d_A)$$

The value of $a$, the hyperbolic distance between $B$ and the center of the unit circle, can now be determined by the hyperbolic law of cosines:
$$cosh(a) = cosh(b)cosh(c) - sihn(b)sinh(c)\cos(\alpha)$$
$$a = arccosh(cosh(b)cosh(c) - sihn(b)sinh(c)\cos(\alpha))$$

The value of $C$ can be also be determined by the hyperbolic law of cosines:
$$\cos(\gamma) = \frac{cosh(a)cosh(b) - cosh(c)}{sinh(a)sinh(b)}$$
$$\gamma = arccos(\frac{cosh(a)cosh(b) - cosh(c)}{sinh(a)sinh(b)})$$

Now, add (or subtract), $\gamma$ from $\epsilon$ to determine the angle of $B$ relative to the unit circle, $\theta$.  The Euclidean distance between $B$ and the center of the unit circle, $d_B$, can be determined using the exponential function:
$$d_B = \frac{e^a - 1}{e^a + 1}$$

Using this distance, the coordinates $x_B$ and $y_B$ of $B$ can be now be determined using basic trigonometric functions:
$$x_B = d_B \cos(\theta)$$
$$y_B = d_B \sin(\theta)$$

The coordinates of destination point $B$ are $(x_B, y_B)$.

Comment: Hopefully this is comprehesible.  It's adapted from Javascript, found here:
https://github.com/ItsNickBarry/hyperbolic-canvas

I imagine there's a more elegant solution, but this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information.

Let $A$ be an *arbitrary* point on the disk.

Draw the hyperbolic line $l$ through $A$ at with slope $\tan\theta$ at $A$.

Now one can select *two* points $B$ and $C$ on $l$ so that $d(A,B)=d(A,C)=d$ ($A$ is the midpoint between $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Would one of those points not be indicated for -π/2 < _θ_ < π/2, and the other for  π/2 < _θ_ < 3π/2 ?

Comment: yes, if you replace "line" with "ray" - but the choice of $A$ remains arbitrary.

Comment: A good point.  I should have said "ray."  It's amateur hour in my time zone.